# Content is not responsive on Mobile devices (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project but, I need help with making an element responsive. The text in the box will come over the image when you resize the browser. Do I have to add a class to the HTML of the item or to the css (the text can't be removed on the resized views). As you can see in the images. [Normal look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAFUi.png) & [Resized look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHnBl.png)

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
     <div class="item">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
           <a><img src="../images/pimg.png"></a>
         </div> <!-- End Image -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4 class="item-name">Item1</h4>
          <p class="item-desc">This is an item's description. Feel free to edit me :)
          <a href="" class="btn btn-rounded btn-default btn-framed btn-small">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- End Middle -->
</div>
```

CSS (Item):

```
.item {
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
 background-color: #fff;
 display: block;
 }
.item:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
box-shadow: 1px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
color: #000;
}
.item-name {
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.item-desc {
padding-left: 15px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #A4A4A4;
}
```

CSS (button):

```
.btn {
-moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
transition: 0.3s ease;
border: none;
outline: none !important;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 4px 12px 6px 12px;
}
.btn.btn-rounded {
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
.btn.btn-framed {
background-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
}
.btn.btn-framed.btn-default {
border-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.2);
color: #1f1f1f;
}
.btn.btn-framed.btn-default:hover {
border-color: #03B01D;
}
.btn.btn-framed.btn-small {
-moz-border-radius: 14px;
-webkit-border-radius: 14px;
border-radius: 14px;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

Comment: add this **img {max-width:100%;}**

Comment: Thanks it worked, but can I add a line of code that will take the ful size of the col with the image? Because now the image is shorter than the box.

Comment: didn't understand well what you mean

Comment: If I resize the browser, the image is smaller (you see a white space under it). Can I fix that with making the image fit the col-md-3 (so it will be the full col wide)?

Comment: ok i understand. If you try to do this the image will be stretched and will loose its proportion, and we cannot do this with simply CSS. As what you want is that both colmun should have the same height which is a bit tricky but it's feasable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.img-fluid` class for making image responsive:

```
<img src="../images/pimg.png" class="img-fluid">
```

Or fluid columns:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
     <div class="item">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md col-md-auto">
           <a><img src="../images/pimg.png" width="150px" height="215px"></a>
         </div> <!-- End Image -->
         <div class="col-md">
           <h4 class="item-name">Item1</h4>
           <p class="item-desc">This is an item's description. Feel free to edit me :)
           <a href="" class="btn btn-rounded btn-default btn-framed btn-small">Learn More</a>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- End Middle -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now the image will not longer show a white space under it. And it looks good!